# Filter data based on id Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have the following `shared.orderItems`. I am using `sharedData.orderITems`'s `id` is used to construct `shared.comboItem`. I wonder how could I able to filter `sharedData.orderItems` data where there is no `comboItemId` equals `id`.

For example, in the following example, there are two items `id` are `71` and `72` are used in `shared.ComboItems`. I want to filter `71` and `72` on `shared.orderItems` and only keep the object id `1`.

```
 (lldb) po sharedData.orderItems
<__NSArrayM 0x174050860>(
{
    Note = "";
    Quantity = 1;
    id = 72;
},
{
    Note = "";
    Quantity = 1;
    id = 71;
},
{
    Note = "";
    Quantity = 2;
    id = 1;
}
)


(lldb) po sharedData.comboItems
<__NSArrayM 0x174247620>(
{
    Note = "";
    Quantity = 1;
    comboItemId = 72;
    id = 3;
},
{
    Note = "";
    Quantity = 1;
    comboItemId = 71;
    id = 19;
},
{
    Note = "";
    Quantity = 1;
    comboItemId = 72;
    id = 20;
},
{
    Note = "";
    Quantity = 1;
    comboItemId = 72;
    id = 21;
}
)
```

Comment: You can use sortDescriptors

Comment: could you please illustrate?

Comment: You need sort or filter?

Comment: I need to filter

Comment: I just updated my answer, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45157482/4061501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried predicate?

1. Filter `shared.comboItems` to get all `comboItemId` into an Array.
2. Use Predicate with `NOT IN` to filter `sharedData.orderItems`

**Solution:**

```
NSArray *unique = [shared.comboItems valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.comboItemId"];
NSPredicate *nonePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"NOT(id IN %@)", unique];
NSArray *filtered = [sharedData.orderItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:nonePredicate];
NSLog(@"Filtered: %@", filtered);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand the question to mean you want to exclude `orderItems` that are referred to by the `comboItemId` attribute in the `comboItems` array.  First collect those:

```
NSMutableSet *excludedIds = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSDictionary *item in sharedData.comboItems) {
    [excludedIds addObject:item[@"comboItemId"]]; // EDIT
}
```

Arrays can be filtered by predicates, and those can be specified with format strings ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)).  So you need:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (id IN %@)", excludedIds];
NSArray *filtered = [sharedData.orderItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: I am getting the following issue `property 'comboItemId' not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'` Shall I use `[excludedIds addObject: [item valueForKey : @"comboItemId" ]]` instead?

Comment: Now I am getting the following error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "id NONE %@"'` in the predicate.

Comment: @hotspring - I think you've used an incorrect format string given in another answer.  See mine `@"NOT (id IN %@)"`

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly inserted other's answer in the middle. That was causing this issue. Since you have answered the question, I am going with your answer first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Key Value Coding - Collection Operator** to get `ids` from Combo items.

**@distinctUnionOfObjects:**  Returns an array of the objects in the property specified in the key path to the right of the operator

```
NSArray *compoIds = [sharedData.CompoItems valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.comboItemId"];

NSPredicate *dupIdsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {
     NSDictionary *orderItemDictionary = (NSDictionary *) obj;
     return  ![compoIds containsObject:[orderItemDictionary valueForKey:@"id"]];
}];

NSArray *unionOfIDs =  [sharedData.orderItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:dupIdsPredicate];

NSLog(@"%@", unionOfIDs);
```